# How do I add the basic Cygwin compiler directories to the path on Windows 10 to enable Netbeans IDE to find the tools collection?

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans, cygwin, windows-10

I'm trying to learn C as new to programming. I have a Windows 10 machine and have installed NetBeans 8.2 C/C++ version.

I am trying to add the correct Cygwin compiler directory to the right path so everything will run smoothly.

I have completed everything below but point 4 in bold.

The instructions below are from :https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html#compilers_windows

which teaches you how to install the basic Cygwin GNU gcc and g++ compilers, make and the gdb debugger.I won't be needing anything more than that to learn basic C.

My Environmental Variables look like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuTLR.png)

When I click paths on Environmental Variables I have a whole list of paths and I don't know how to 'Add the path to the cygwin-directory\bin directory to the Path variable' in point 4 below.

**Please, how do I do this and to which path or am I adding a whole new path?
Any help is most appreciated.**

My list of path looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBKIL.png)

' To install the GNU gcc and g++ compilers, make, and gdb debugger from cygwin.com:
1.Refer to the Cygwin User's Guide for complete information about installing and using Cygwin.

2.Download the Cygwin setup-x86.exe (32-bit installation) or setup-x86_64.exe (64-bit installation) program by clicking Install Cygwin in the left navigation bar, or by clicking the direct setup-x86.exe or setup-x86_64.exe link. 
Note: The bitness of Windows OS, Java, and NetBeans IDE installed on your machine must match. For example, if you are running the 64-bit version of Windows operating system, 64-bit Java and 64-bit Cygwin (that is setup-x86_64.exe) are required to be installed. See issue 234221 for details.

3. Run the downloaded Cygwin installer. Accept the defaults until you reach the Select Your Internet Connection page. Select the option on this page that is best for you. Click Next.
4. On the Choose Download Site page, choose a download site you think might be relatively close to you. Click Next.
5. On the Select Packages page you select the packages to download. Click the + next to Devel to expand the development tools category. You may want to resize the window so you can see more of it at one time.
6. Select each package you want to download by clicking the Skip label next to it, which reveals the version number of the package to download. At a minimum, select •gcc-core: C compiler 
   •gcc-g++: C++ compiler 
   •gdb: The GNU Debugger 
   •make: the GNU version of the 'make' utility 
   Packages that are required by the packages you select are automatically selected as well.

7.Click Next to connect to the download site and download the packages you selected, and click Finish when the installation is complete.

8. Now add the Cygwin compiler directory to your path to enable NetBeans IDE to find the tools collection:

1.Open the Control Panel:
 - On Windows XP select Start > Settings > Control Panel and double-click System. 
 - On Windows 7, type var in the Start menu's search box to quickly find a link to Edit the system environment variables.

2.Select the Advanced tab and click Environment Variables.

3.In the System Variables panel of the Environment Variables dialog, select the Path variable and click Edit.

**4.**Add the path to the cygwin-directory\bin directory to the Path variable, and click OK. By default, cygwin-directory is C:\cygwin (for 32 bit Cygwin distribution) or C:\cygwin64 (for 64 bit Cygwin distribution). Directory names must be separated with a semicolon. Your edited path should look something like %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem;C:\cygwin\bin

5.Click OK in the Environment Variables dialog and the System Properties dialog.

6.See Verifying the Installation to verify that the tools were installed correctly for the NetBeans IDE.'

Comment: Windows 10 is a 64 bit OS.